# Count if certain items are adjacent in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following list:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,9,4,5,8,9]
```

I need to find if 8,9 are adjacent to each other and if so return the number of instances where they are adjacent.

I initially tried

```
p=(any([8,9] == a[i:i+2] for i in xrange(len(a) - 1)))
    print p
```

It returns `True` but I need to retrieve the count. How can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate Elimination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770055/duplicate-elimination)

Answer (score 1):

This pythonic solution should give you your answer, as well as having all possible answers for unique pairs of elements in your list.

```
from collections import Counter
zipped = Counter(zip(a, a[1:]))
zipped[(8,9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) will not give you a count. It only tells you whether the condition is true anywhere inside of the given iterable `a`.

Remove `any` and you end up with a generator expression:

```
p=( [8,9] == a[i:i+2] for i in xrange(len(a) - 1) )
```

If we turn that generator expression into a list we get:

```
>>> p = list( [8,9] == a[i:i+2] for i in xrange(len(a) - 1) )
>>> print(p)
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, True]
```

To get the final count call the `count` method of `list` with a parameter of `True` (you want the count of `True` items):

```
>>> p.count(True)
3
```

---

Or you could convert your generator expression to a list comprehension and move the condition to become an if statement after the for loop which keeps only those items that match the condition. The count is then the length of the list:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,9,4,5,8,9]
>>> pairs = [True for i in xrange(len(a) - 1) if [8,9] == a[i:i+2]]
>>> pairs
[True, True, True]
>>> print(len(pairs))
3
```